# jQuery Autocomplete: How to get original user text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

In a jQuery autocomplete plugin, where is the value the the user originally typed stored? For example, look at http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/. If you type 'j' in the search box, you see some options. You can use the arrow keys to go through the options, and go back up to the 'j' that you originally typed even though it doesn't appear as one of the options in the dropdown.

I want to access that value when the user selects a suggestion, so I can get both the value they typed and the value they selected. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: When I use the demos on jquery UI's site, I can't get back up to the 'j'.

Comment: It works for me (on chrome). That question is interesting, I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: @SamHuckaby select a suggestion and press <kbd>esc</kbd>

Comment: This is the keyboard interaction for DOWN/UP arrow key: Move focus to the next item. If on last item, move focus to the input. If on the input, move focus to the first item and vice versa. What was the result with $(this).val(); ? Have you tried it?

Comment: @JoeyEzekiel I tried that in the 'select' function, and it gave me the value of the selected item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use the open event to capture the original input whenever the list is opened or updated.  Inside that event capture the original input.  You can then stash this value in a variable or a hidden element to be used later.  Let me know if you need more details.

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags,
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $("#original-content").html($("#tags").val());
    }
});
```

See the working jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rlouie/p7dthpz0/1/

Comment: Ah perfect! I think that should do it. Still a little curious if it's available anywhere in the 'select' function, and how the plugin itself keeps track of the value so you can select it again. But this should be good enough for my purposes.

Comment: The select function fires on the actual selection, but when that event is fired it appears the value of the input is already set, and so you cannot retrieve the original value in select.  If this answer works, could you mark it as an answer please?

Answer (score 1):

So I've been digging a little into the source. The plugin keeps track of the value entered in a *private* attribute of the plugin, called term.
I have not been able to accces it outside from the source code :/